# How to make the stylus more efficient

Tags: css, stylus

I have the following code and wish how I can do it in stylus

CSS

```
h1 {
    font-size: 36px
}
h2 {
    font-size: 32px
}
h3 {
    font-size: 28px
}
h4 {
    font-size: 24px
}
h5 {
    font-size: 20px
}
h6 {
    font-size: 16px
}
```

Stylus

```
for num in (1..6)
    h-{num}
        font-size 32px
```

First would be to loop in the heading and then nose as I would do another loop for the font-size

Comment: The documentation for Stylus does not suggest you can use `for ... in` to generate rule selectors, only properties: http://stylus-lang.com/docs/iteration.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
size= 36px 32px 28px 24px 20px 16px
for num,$s in  size
    h{$s+1} num
```

click [here](http://stylus-lang.com/try.html#?code=size%3D%2036px%2032px%2028px%2024px%2020px%2016px%0Afor%20num%2C%24s%20in%20%20size%0A%09h%7B%24s%2B1%7D%20num) for demo

Comment: Gracias! funcionó perfectamente